# Directive with ng-model-options can't add new elements to model array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

http://plnkr.co/edit/m7Pt6FdDrOThKEXoohS9?p=preview

When editing the list, it is supposed to discard the changes when pressing 'Discard', and save the changes when pressing 'Save'. This part is working. However, when going in to edit mode, I push an almost empty object to the array of data so that a user can add new elements, and remove it if they don't type in anything. Later on, I will look for any changes to the input and add more empty elements.

The problem is, the saving works on existing elements, but adding new elements doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log("Data change");
                console.log(newVal);
            }, true);
```

This code always shows an empty new object even though the user has typed something in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
            if (angular.equals({tag: '', priority: ''}, $scope.data[i-1])) {
                console.log($scope.data[i-1]);
                $scope.data.splice(i-1, 1);
                console.log("splicing 1 - " + (i - 1));
            }
```

The added item is always empty. This is due to the fact that AngularJS doesn't understand that the `$scope` isupdated. The solution is to wrap it into a `$timeout` so the `$scope` is updated with the new value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8FczdIhIJxKHslcr7Hve?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. For future reference, when should one consider a timeout as a solution? It's really odd behavior, but is there any logical arguments and idea behind it?

Comment: Generally, when there is some async binding occurs. The $timeout assures you that a $digest cycle will happen afterwards